# Declare static member variables like Java's in Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, class, static

How can I make an Objective-C class with class-level variables like this Java class?

```
public class test
{

    public static final String tableName = "asdfas";    
    public static final String id_Column = "_id";
    public static final String Z_ENT_Column = "Z_ENT";

}
```

I want to access them without making an instance, like:

```
String abc = test.tableName;
```

Comment: Are you asking about class methods in Obj-c ?

Comment: static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reuseStaticIdentifier";

Comment: nope, please see the java class in question, I want something like same.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like you want to create constants (since you are using `final` in your question). In Objective-C, you can use `extern` for that.

Do something like this:

1) Create a new Objective-C class named Constants.

2) In the header (.h) file:

```
extern const NSString *SERVICE_URL;
```

3) In the implementation (.m) file:

```
NSString *SERVICE_URL = @"http://something/services";
```

4) Add `#import "Constants.h"` to any class where you want to use it

5) Access directly as `NSString *url = SERVICE_URL;`

---

If you don't want to create constants and simply want to use `static` in Objective-C, unfortunately you can only use `static` in the implementation (.m) file. And they can be accessed directly without prefixing the Class Name.

For example:

```
static NSString *url = @"something";
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: extern are not treated as best way of programming.

Comment: The `const` in `const NSString *` is not meaningful. you are not allowed to manipulate the object pointed to by the pointer directly anyway

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: what's wrong with `extern`? In the original Java code, those variable are specifically `public`, which means they should be usable from other files. `extern` is exactly what allows this.

Comment: @newacct: I would prefer to share a data throughout the application by means of SharedInstance/Singleton class

Comment: Hey I made a gist some time ago, not ARC compatible but it can actually be used in ARC by using the assign methods and specifying strong or weak references. It's a bit closer to what the original question asked: https://gist.github.com/darionco/03649feeee57f86fee3f

Answer (score 31):

Try it....

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reuseStaticIdentifier";
```

You can access direct value using synthesis property
or you can use NSUserDefaults for store and retrive value

Description

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
+(NSString *)myFullName;
@end
```

Implementation :

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
static NSString *fullName = @"Hello World";

+(NSString *)myFullName{
  return fullName;
}
@end
```

Use:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
  NSLog(@"%@",[MyClass myFullName]); //no instance but you are getting the value.
}

@end
```

Hope i helped.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use a class method to access anything that can be called **without making an instance**.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
+(NSString *)myFullName;
@end
```

Implementation :

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
   static NSString *fullName=@"anoop vaidya";

+(NSString *)myFullName;{
    return fullName;
}
@end
```

How to use:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    NSLog(@"%@",[MyClass myFullName]); //no instance but you are getting the value.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C doesn't have class variables

I would recommend putting the static NSString in the implementation file of your class, and provide class methods to access it

```
@implementation MyClass

static  NSString* str;
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be done like that:

```
@interface Test
 {
   static NSString *tableName;
 }

+(NSString *) getTableName;
@end

@implementation Test
+ (NSString *)getTableName
 {
    return tableName;
 }
@end
```

And then you fetch it:

```
NSString *name = [Test getTableName];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way and more used is to use enums such as

```
enum{
    GSPAYMENT_METHOD_CARD = 1,
    GSPAYMENT_METHOD_CASH = 2,
    GSPAYMENT_METHOD_VOID = 3
};
typedef NSUInteger PaymentMethodType;
```

Just before the `@interface GSPaymentMethod`

This way you can use those constants anywhere by just including the `.h` file

For example

`[self newPayment:GSPAYMENT_METHOD_CASH]`